# Missing Title on Drupal Panelizer: PHP Fatal error and ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

To summarize, the titles do not show up on my article pages and I cannot configure the context and content on the layout wizard for Panelizer. The issue happens when going to Manage Display >> Panelize this view mode >> and edit one of the "Default displays available for this view mode". Every time I try to configure the settings I am getting the dreaded "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." message or the white screen of death (WSD). The following errors are in my log.

> PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Drupal\panelizer\Plugin\PanelsPattern\PanelizerPattern::getDefaultContexts(Drupal\user\SharedTempStoreFactory $tempstore, $tempstore_id, $machine_name) must be compatible with Drupal\panels\Plugin\PanelsPattern\DefaultPattern::getDefaultContexts(Drupal\Core\TempStore\SharedTempStoreFactory $tempstore, $tempstore_id, $machine_name) in /mysite.com/modules/contrib/panelizer/src/Plugin/PanelsPattern/PanelizerPattern.php on line 14
>
> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\ctools\Form\ManageContext::__construct(), 2 passed in /mysite.com/modules/contrib/panelizer/src/Form/PanelizerWizardContextForm.php on line 53 and exactly 3 expected in /mysite.com/modules/contrib/ctools/src/Form/ManageContext.php on line 70 #0 /mysite.com/modules/contrib/panelizer/src/Form/PanelizerWizardContextForm.php(53): Drupal\ctools\Form\ManageContext->__construct(Object(Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager), Object(Drupal\autosave_form\Form\AutosaveFormBuilder))

Comment: Maybe ask this question on [drupal.stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This patch worked using composer to add patch, till the next update!
https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer/issues/3031671#comment-13052581